# Get local min and max values from data array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, f#

I have a date/some kind of value array. When I draw it as a chart it looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to find its local min and max points. I signed them by blue points on my chart above.

Is there any built in support in .net/linq/c#/f# to get local min max values of an array/list? I googled this topic. I just want to double check it before coding it by my myself and before reinventing the wheel.

*Pls. check my sample chart and the blue points on it, it is not just a simple getting min max values from an array!*

Comment: What do you mean by `local min and max`?

Comment: "local" can mean any number of things. You have to define your criteria and then write code to identify those points. "Check out my blue points" doesn't tell us much. Do you want the min and max Y values within a certain range of X values? Or are you looking for min and max values between inflection points? Without a good definition of your criteria, there's no way we can give anything like a good answer.

Comment: @Tom, I've seen the blue points but still don't understand what you mean.  Can you please explain?

Comment: May be it is more clear: This data comes from a machine and based on its operation, lets say it for simplicity as 'fuel level of the mmachine', so my data fuel level vs time. So, data frequency is up to its operation, if it works, I have data at every 5 secs, if it does not work, I have this data once a day.I have to find points, where fuel was tanked to the machine and where fuel was stolen from it.

Comment: So what you're really looking for is inflection points. In your case, any time the amount of fuel in the machine increased, you can say with some certainty that fuel was added. And if the amount of fuel decreased by more than some defined value over a short period of time (i.e. the thing burns 5 gallons per hour, but it lost a gallon in a minute), then it's likely that fuel was stolen. What you want is to identify points where the change over time is more than the expected value.

Comment: @Tom, I think what Abe was implying is that defining precisely what you mean by `local min and max` **is** the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in function in .NET (or F# libraries) that would do that automatically.

To give you some initial idea - it is quite easy to solve this in F# if you only had precise data (i.e. ignoring small spikes in your chart) such that no two following values in the array are the same.

In that case, you can find a minimum by looking for three following values such that the middle value is smaller than the previous and also smaller than the next value. This detects shapes like:

```
__  __
  \/
```

For example, if you have `values` containing your data, you can write:

```
let values = [ 1.0; 2.0; 1.5; 1.0; 4.0; 2.0 ]
// Add indices as the first element of a tuple (so that we can identify positions)
let valuesIndexed = values |> Seq.mapi (fun i v -> i, v)

// Use 'windowed' to create sliding window of size 3 and then 'choose'
// indices where previous value and following value are both larger
let mins = 
  valuesIndexed |> Seq.windowed 3 |> Seq.choose (fun arr ->
    match arr.[0], arr.[1], arr.[2] with
    | (_, vpre), (i, v), (_, vpost) when vpre > v && vpost > v -> Some i
    | _ -> None)
```

This is not going to work for the data in your chart, because it is oversimplified, but it should give you something to start with. In practice, you'll probably need to add some smoothing (to avoid identifying all the spikes as local minima/maxima).

Comment: Thank you for this elegant bit of code :) I'm guessing that you can also use a similar windowed technique to create a moving root mean square value of previously seen values and find a minima/maxima that devaiates sufficiently from this upon which the RMS value would be reset and you would proceed to find the next minima/maxima.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to manually write this, since to calculate a local minima/maxima you'd have multiple parameters to consider such as timeframe, rate of change, etc. There are algorithms out there you could use to do this, but it isn't implemented in the .NET libraries.

Comment: No, it is not enough for me, it would be too simple. I don't want to get the max an min for the whole data, if you see my blue points on my chart. I want to get local min max values, so it is about some trend analyzing and data filtering also.

Answer (score 0):

using Linq try something like this:

```
YourArray.Where(/*your condition for a "local" portion of the array*/).Min(t => t.Date);
YourArray.Where(/*your condition for a "local" portion of the array*/).Max(t => t.Date);
```

Comment: Which local portions to use...it can be various.

Comment: I'm not sure what conditions you are using to define the various "local portions" of the array so it's hard to say.  Can you give more detail on how you are defining this?

Comment: It can be various. This data comes from a machine and based on its operation, lets say it for simplicity as 'fuel level of the mmachine', so my data fuel level vs time. So, data frequency is up to its operation, if it works, I have data at every 5 secs, if it does not work, I have this data once a day.